# Object files compiled with `g++ -std=c++1y` won't link

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm on Linux with `g++ 5.3.0`.

I thought I'd make myself an object file that, when linked, would initialized global variables `Argc` and `Argv` so that the `main` arguments would be available throughout the process.

Argv.hh:

```
#pragma once
extern char** Argv;
extern int Argc;
```

Argv.cc:

```
char** Argv;
int Argc;
static int set_argv(int argc, char** argv, char** env) { Argc = argc; Argv = argv; return 0; }
/* Put the function into the init_array */
__attribute__((section(".init_array"))) static void *ctr = (void*)&set_argv;
```

main.cc

```
#include "Argv.hh"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  for (int i = 0; i < Argc; ++i){
    puts(Argv[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My original build script was:

```
com='g++ -std=c++1y'
for cc in *.cc; do $com -c $cc; done
g++ *.o
```

but it kept giving me a linking error. So I changed `com` to 
`gcc -x c -std=c99` and it worked, and it also worked with plain `com=g++`.

Each of the three compilers successfully compiles, only the linking part fails with `g++ -std=c++1y`.

`nm *.o` outputs:

For `gcc -x c -std=c99`:

```
Argv.o:
0000000000000004 C Argc
0000000000000008 C Argv
0000000000000000 t ctr
0000000000000000 t set_argv

main.o:
                 U Argc
                 U Argv
0000000000000000 T main
                 U puts
```

For `g++`:

```
Argv.o:
0000000000000008 B Argc
0000000000000000 B Argv
0000000000000000 t _ZL3ctr
0000000000000000 t _ZL8set_argviPPcS0_

main.o:
                 U Argc
                 U Argv
0000000000000000 T main
                 U puts
```

And for `g++ -std=c++1y`:

```
Argv.o:
0000000000000008 B Argc
0000000000000000 B Argv
0000000000000000 t _ZL3ctr
0000000000000000 t _ZL8set_argviPPcS0_

main.o:
0000000000000008 B Argc
0000000000000000 B Argv
0000000000000000 T main
                 U puts
```

The last set of object files fails to link with

```
main.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Argv'
Argv.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
main.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `Argc'
Argv.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does `g++ -std=c++1y` generate B symbols for `extern` declarations when the other two generate (as they should?) undefined references? Is this a bug?

Comment: What happens if you use `cstdio.h` instead of `stdio.h` for the C++ tests? Just taking a wild guess here.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that `nm` shows a non-zero default value for variables that are in the BSS section (`B`) -- not sure what is up with that. Probably unrelated to your issues, though.

Comment: Hmm, never mind my previous comment. It seems the output from `nm` is the relative address of the variable, not its initial value as the documentation would have me believe.

Comment: Can't reproduce here with gcc-5.3.1 on Debian, I get the expected `U` in all cases.

Comment: Can't reproduce this [online Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WMIc6G1i0X3bFtpD) either, which uses 5.3.0. Sounds like a bug in your upstream package.